# Pandas Long to Wide for Categorical Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Usually when we want to transform a dataframe long to wide in Pandas, we use *pivot* or *pivot_table*, or *unstack*, or *groupby*, but that works well when there are aggregatable elements. How do we transform in the same manner a categorical dataframe?

Example:

```
d = {'Fruit':['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Kiwi'], 
'Color1':['Red', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Green'],
'Color2':['Red', 'Red', 'Green', 'Brown'],'Color3':[np.nan,np.nan,'Red',np.nan]}

pd.DataFrame(d)

    Fruit   Color1  Color2  Color3
0   Apple   Red     Red     NaN
1   Apple   Yellow  Red     NaN
2   Apple   Red     Green   Red
3   Kiwi    Green   Brown   NaN
```

Should become something like this:

```
d = {'Fruit':['Apple','Kiwi'], 
     'Color1':['Red','Green'],
     'Color1_1':['Yellow',np.nan],
     'Color1_2':['Red',np.nan],
     'Color2':['Red', 'Brown'],
     'Color2_1':['Red',np.nan],
     'Color2_2':['Green',np.nan],
     'Color3':[np.nan,np.nan],
     'Color3_1':[np.nan,np.nan],
     'Color3_2':['Red',np.nan]
    }

pd.DataFrame(d)

    Fruit   Color1  Color1_1    Color1_2    Color2  Color2_1    Color2_2    Color3  Color3_1    Color3_2
0   Apple   Red     Yellow      Red         Red     Red         Green       NaN     NaN         Red
1   Kiwi    Green   NaN         NaN         Brown   NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get the counts, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) on it as the columns, then set the column names, with:

```
df = df.assign(idx=df.groupby('Fruit').cumcount()).pivot(index='Fruit',columns='idx')
print(df.set_axis([f'{x}_{y}' if y != 0 else x for x, y in df.columns], axis=1).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   Fruit Color1 Color1_1 Color1_2 Color2 Color2_1 Color2_2 Color3 Color3_1 Color3_2
0  Apple    Red   Yellow      Red    Red      Red    Green    NaN      NaN      Red
1   Kiwi  Green      NaN      NaN  Brown      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Matches your output exactly.